why can "ctr images list" not show images pulled by command of "crictl pull"?
why can "ctr images list" not show images pulled by command of "crictl pull"?
After install containerd , using crictl to pull busybox successed
sudo crictl pull busybox

but using command of "sudo ctr images list" , got nothing .

That's because the image that k8s pulls is stored in a separate namespace.
Try this instead:
ctr -n k8s.io images list

